# HP ALM - download a resource under a specific folder in the Test Resource module

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center

We are using ALM 12.  We have multiple folders in our Test Resources module, and some of the resources stored in these folders have the same name as in other folders.  I am able to download a resource using the name, but can't figure out how to get a resource under a specific folder.  Anyone know how to download a resource specifying the folder to download it from?

e.g
Folder1
   mysheet.xls
Folder2
   mysheet.xls

I want to download Folder2\mysheet.xls and not Folder1\mysheet.xls

Answer (score 0):

You could download the resource by resource id rather than resource name.

Below is VBS sample (with OTA API) for your reference:

```
Option Explicit

Dim tdc, cust, resource

set tdc = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
tdc.InitConnectionEx "http://YourALMServer:Port/qcbin"
tdc.Login "username", "password"
tdc.Connect "domainName", "projectName"

# 1001 is the resource id which you want to download.
set resource = tdc.QCResourceFactory.Item("1001")
# "C:\\tmp\\" is the local path where you want to place the downloaded resource
resource.DownloadResource "C:\\tmp\\", TRUE

tdc.Disconnect
tdc.Logout
tdc.ReleaseConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Dim objCon, cust, resource
set objCon= CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
objCon.InitConnectionEx "http://YourALMServer:Port/qcbin"
objCon.Login "username", "password"
objCon.Connect "domainName", "projectName"

Set oResourceFolder = objCon.QCResourceFolderFactory
Set oFilter = oResourceFolder.Filter
oFilter.Filter("RFO_NAME") ="abc" \\ abc is your folder name 
Set oList = oFilter.NewList()
set oChild = oList.item(1).QCResourceFactory.NewList("") 
''assuming that there is only 1 folder with name "abc" in Test Resources section
For i =1 to oChild.count Step 1
 oChild.item(i).DownloadResource "c:\\a", TRUE
''c:\\a is the location where we need to safe the resource
next
set objCon = Nothing
```